# how to delete some line in CSV file , using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Please See Example.

i want to delete 1,2 lines in csv file, and use pandas

i try read_csv function in pandas library but pandas can not loading this CSV file

i can do delete line in Excel, but CSV file to many have.

so i want to delete line process in python.

Please let me know solution in python

Ex )

```
filename : xxxxxx
     time : xxxxx
     output1 output2 output3 output4 output5
        1       1       1      1       1
        1       1       1      1       1
        1       1       1      1       1
```

Comment: filename : xxxxxx time : xxxxx output1 output2 output3 output4 output5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' `read_csv` function has a `skiprows` argument, which will let pandas know to skip either a fixed number of lines or a list of line numbers. In this case, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=2)
```

Please see use in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

PS: This assumes the actual data is comma-separated. Otherwise, you can define a custom delimiter with `sep` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is likely having a hard time parsing your CSV because of the filename and time data at the top of your file. If you delete those, and then use `read_csv()` in pandas again, it should not have any issues reading a tab or space delimited file.

EDIT: @Avidiotic's response is a better solution if you don't want to manually delete the lines, or you want to persist the filename and time data.